# Error with variable names when creating an update trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that allows for the input of clothe articles that have the sizes small-large, but the trigger will change the size to S M or L depending on the insert.

I am getting a bad bind variable error on my if statement and I'm not sure why, as it is the same as the column name in my Products table.

**Products table:**

```html
CREATE TABLE "user"."PRODUCTS" 
   (    "PID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER, 
    "PRODUCT_SIZE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_VALUE" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("PID")
```

**Size Trigger:**

```html
create or replace TRIGGER sizeTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON PRODUCTS
BEGIN
   --smalls--
    IF :NEW.product_size = 's' THEN
    ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE := 'S';
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'S' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'S';
     elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'small'THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'S';
       elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'SMALL' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'S';
    --MEDIUM--
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'm' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'M';
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'm' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'M';
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'medium' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'M';
        elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'MEDIUM' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'M';
     --large
      elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'l' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'L';
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'L' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'L';
    elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'large' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'L';
        elsif ::NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'LARGE' THEN
       ::NEW.product_size := 'L';
      else
          raise exception_error;        
        END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exception_error THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size must be "s,m,l,small, medium, large");
END;
```

Comment: Get rid of all your double quotes around column definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working trigger. I have simplified the logic a little bit.

```
create or replace TRIGGER sizeTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON PRODUCTS
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  exception_error       EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF upper(:NEW.product_size)  in ('S','SMALL') THEN :NEW.product_size :='S';
   ELSIF upper(:NEW.product_size)  in ('M','MEDIUM') THEN :NEW.product_size  :='M';
   ELSIF upper(:NEW.product_size)  in ('L','LARGE') THEN :NEW.product_size  :='L';
   ELSE
     raise exception_error; 
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exception_error THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size must be "s,m,l,small, medium, large"');
   RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: Hey this complies properly can you explain what i did wrong? I know i had double '::'

Comment: 1) No FOR EACH ROW

Comment: 2) Not closed string in put_line call 3) ::NEW instead of :NEW

Comment: Interesting idk how i missed that when writting it thanks alot!

Comment: Just tested it and it works for the most part but it let through this insert: INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (pid, product_name, quantity, product_size, product_value)
Values(2, 'Product 2', 3,'very big', 51.00);

Comment: add raise; at the end of exception block. (look at the answer)

Comment: i think its seeing the error but still processing the insert into the database

Comment: I doubt it. If you have added "RAISE;" at the end it will not insert the record. I think you are looking at the records inserted before.

Answer (score 1):

In real life we would aim to use a check constraint to enforce the business rule.

```
alter table products
    add constraint check_product_size
       check (product_size in ('S', 'M', 'L'));
```

I would prefer the application to provide the user with a selection of valid sizes; people find it confusing if the data they enter is mysteriously changed or missing when they query it back. But if you want to do it, here is the simplest trigger possible (in conjunction with check constraint above):

```
create or replace trigger sizetrigger
before insert or update
   on products
   for each row
begin
   :new.product_size := upper(substr(:new.product_size,1,1));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single `:` not `::` for `:new`

```
create or replace TRIGGER sizeTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON PRODUCTS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   --smalls--
    IF :NEW.product_size = 's' THEN
    :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE := 'S';
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'S' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'S';
     elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'small'THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'S';
       elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'SMALL' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'S';
    --MEDIUM--
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'm' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'M';
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'm' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'M';
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'medium' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'M';
        elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'MEDIUM' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'M';
     --large
      elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'l' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'L';
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'L' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'L';
    elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'large' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'L';
        elsif :NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE = 'LARGE' THEN
       :NEW.product_size := 'L';
      else
          raise exception_error;        
        END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exception_error THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size must be "s,m,l,small, medium, large"');
END;
```

Also I would refactor your code. Instead of such long cascade of `elsif` you can have:

```
if upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('S', 'SMALL') then :NEW.product_size := 'S';
if upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('M', 'MEDIUM') then :NEW.product_size := 'M';
if upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('L', 'LARGE') then :NEW.product_size := 'L';
```

So final version would be:

```
create or replace TRIGGER sizeTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON PRODUCTS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      if upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('S', 'SMALL') then :NEW.product_size := 'S';
      elsif upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('M', 'MEDIUM') then :NEW.product_size := 'M';
      elsif upper(:NEW.PRODUCT_SIZE) in ('L', 'LARGE') then :NEW.product_size := 'L';
      else
          raise exception_error;        
      END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exception_error THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size must be "s,m,l,small, medium, large"');
END;
```

Comment: I think that helped but im still getting that bad bind variable error (PLS-00049) and a compiler error ORA-04082: New Old references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: @nagel9 Try now `FOR EACH ROW` added